# Is there a name for collections of sets that are closed under countable unions and intersections, but not complements?

Tags: measure-theory

I dug around online, but couldn't seem to find an answer. Such collections exist, for example if $X$ is a set with $\#X > 2$ then for a fixed $x\in X$, the collection $\{M \subset X : x\notin M\}$ has the desired properties.